# Running aggregate column among pairs of varying order

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have such data:

```
Id, Team1, Team2, Score1, Score2
--------------------------------
1,  Aaa,   Bbb,   10,     8 
2,  Aaa,   Bbb,   6,      8 
3,  Aaa,   Bbb,   6,      5 
4,  Bbb,   Aaa,   9,      7 
5,  Aaa,   Ccc,   12,     6
```

How I can get a column with difference between scores among teams (running aggregate)?
Example:

```
Id, Team1, Team2, Score1, Score2  Abs(DIFF)
--------------------------------  ---------
1,  Aaa,   Bbb,   10,     8       2
2,  Aaa,   Bbb,   6,      8       0
3,  Aaa,   Bbb,   6,      5       1
4,  Bbb,   Aaa,   7,      9       3       
5,  Aaa,   Ccc,   12,     6       6
```

Please notice two things in the above example:

- Order of teams among pair may vary (like in between row 1 and 4)
- Table may contain many team pairs

Is it possible to get this DIFF column without using cursor or an update trick? 
Query has to run on SQL Server 2008.

I rarely do DB work so simple explanations are welcome.

**UPDATE** Additional explanation:

- In the first row the DIFF is 2 because team Aaa won by two points
- In the second row the DIFF is 0 because this time team Bbb won by two points
- In the third row the DIFF is 1 because team Aaa won again (by one point)
- In the forth row the DIFF is 3 because team Aaa won again (by two points)

So by looking at the DIFF value, one should be able to answer a question like "what is the current difference in score between teams?".

Comment: I am not able to understand the logic behind your output result.Could you explain?

Comment: @AnandPhadke I've added some clarification.

Comment: It doesn't help though that the sample data doesn't match between the examples you give.

Comment: Fifth row is a different pair (Aaa-Ccc, not Aaa-Bbb) so the DIFF among Aaa and Ccc teams is simply 6 (there was a question here about it before...)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what doesn't match?

Comment: The third row in your first sample has score 5 and 5. The 4th row has scores 9 for Bbb and 7 for Aaa. In your second sample, the third row scores are 6 and 5, and the fourth row scores switch sides (I've already said as much, more tersely, in my answer if you care to look at it).

Comment: +1 Upps sorry for that, my fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with your second sample data (row 3 is tied in first sample, and row 4's score switch sides):

```
declare @t table (Id int not null,Team1 char(3) not null,Team2 char(3) not null,
    Score1 int not null,Score2 int not null)
insert into @t(Id, Team1, Team2, Score1, Score2) values
(1,  'Aaa',   'Bbb',   10,     8), 
(2,  'Aaa',   'Bbb',   6,      8), 
(3,  'Aaa',   'Bbb',   6,      5), 
(4,  'Bbb',   'Aaa',   7,      9), 
(5,  'Aaa',   'Ccc',   12,     6)

;With NormTeams as (
    select Id,
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 ELSE Team2 END as Team1,
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Team2 ELSE Team1 END as Team2,
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Score1 ELSE Score2 END as Score1,
        CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN Score2 ELSE Score1 END as Score2,
        (Score1 - Score2) * CASE WHEN Team1 < Team2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END as ScoreDiff
    from @t
), MatchingTeams as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By Team1,Team2 ORDER BY ID) as rn
    from NormTeams
)
select *,
 (SELECT SUM(ScoreDiff) from MatchingTeams mt2 where
      mt2.Team1 = mt1.Team1 and mt2.Team2 = mt1.Team2 and
      mt2.rn <= mt1.rn) as RunningDiff
from MatchingTeams mt1
```

There's unfortunately nothing much that can make it neater until you can use the [2012 windowed aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Result:

```
Id          Team1 Team2 Score1      Score2      ScoreDiff   rn                   RunningDiff
----------- ----- ----- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
1           Aaa   Bbb   10          8           2           1                    2
2           Aaa   Bbb   6           8           -2          2                    0
3           Aaa   Bbb   6           5           1           3                    1
4           Aaa   Bbb   9           7           2           4                    3
5           Aaa   Ccc   12          6           6           1                    6
```

You'll notice that the first thing I do is the obvious - switch teams and scores around, if necessary, so that the rest of the query can assume that they *do* appear in a consistent order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Edit: Fixed for team1 & team2 swaps.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Id
        , Team1
        , Team2
        , Score1
        , Score2
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.Teams ORDER BY ???) AS Row
    FROM MyTable
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Team1 + '_' + Team2 -- Use something else than '_' if this caracter can exist in team's names
        WHERE Team1 < Team2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            Team2 + '_' + Team1
        WHERE Team1 > Team2
    ) AS X(Teams)
)
SELECT
        T1.Id
        , T1.Team1
        , T1.Team2
        , T1.Score1
        , T1.Score2
        , ABS((T1.Score1 + ISNULL(T2.Score1, 0)) - (T1.Score2 + ISNULL(T2.Score2, 0))) AS Abs(DIFF)
FROM CTE AS T1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(T2.Score1) AS Score1
        , SUM(T2.Score2) AS Score2
    FROM CTE AS T2
    WHERE T2.Teams = T1.Teams
    AND T2.Row < T1.Row
) AS T2
```

Comment: Your `PARTITION BY` in the CTE will split the row numbers into two separate partitions when the teams switch places.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
select id,Team1,Team2,Score1,Score2,0 as RS1,0 as RS2,ABS(Score1-Score2) as DIFF from Table1 where id=1
UNION ALL
select t1.id,t1.Team1,t1.Team2,t1.Score1,t1.Score2,c.score1+t1.Score1,c.score2+t1.Score2,ABS((c.score1+t1.Score1)-(c.score2+t1.Score2)) as DIFF 
from Table1 t1 inner join CTE c 
on c.id+1=t1.id and ((t1.Team1 = c.team1 and t1.Team2 = c.Team2) or (t1.Team2 = c.team1 and t1.Team1 = c.Team2)) 
)
,CTE1 As
(
select * from CTE
union
select id,Team1,Team2,Score1,Score2,0,0,ABS(Score1-Score2) as DIFF from Table1 where id not in(select id from CTE)
)

select id,Team1,Team2,Score1,Score2,DIFF from CTE1
```